# How to make all the content fit the size of ViewPort3D automatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, viewport3d

I have a ViewPort3D, Which has been inserted many objects. the ViewPort3D has its width and height defined. how can I make the objects displayed wholly inside the width and height

Comment: The answer depends on the camera the viewport3d is using and, depending on the type of the camera, the location of the object (distance between camera and object) So to answer this question more details are needed.

Comment: <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camera" FarPlaneDistance="100" LookDirection="0,0,-10"
     UpDirection="0,1,0" NearPlaneDistance="0" Position="0,0,7"
     FieldOfView="50" />                                         I am Adding all 3D shapes in this viewport3D and whenever I add new object which is bigger than the height and width of viewport I have to rotate the whole 3D scene to look for the object ....is there any solution to it?please suggest any solution

Comment: I am still struggling to achieve this...any help will be massively appreciated!